# Set maximum width for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` with system and custom cells.

[image: Screenshot]

Problem 1) Top two cells with `Default` style.

`titleLabel` have a name, `accessoryView` have a `UITextField`.

On iPad, if textfield contains long text - it overlaps label.

How can I limit maximum width for textfield? VFL?

Problem 2) Bottom custom cells have some elements (labels, buttons) contained in cell's `contentView`.

Sizes and position of elements inside `contentView` are controlled by VFL.

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
{
    super.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    let img = UIImageView()
    contentView.addSubview(img)

    let label = UILabel()
    contentView.addSubview(label)

    let button = UIButton()
    contentView.addSubview(button)

    contentView.vfls([ // just adds NSLayoutConstraint
        "H:|-15-[type(20)]-[label]-10-[delete(30)]-7-|",
        "V:|-15-[type(20)]->=0-|",
        "V:|[label]|",
        "V:|-10-[delete(30)]->=0-|"
    ], views: [
        "type": img,
        "label": label,
        "delete": button,
    ])
}
```

How can I limit maximum width of cell (like top two system cells) and hold it at center of cell.

I tried to place all elements in new container view and control it size and position via VFL too - but no luck.

Comment: y dont u use width constraint for textfield ?

Comment: Than I need to hardcode maximum width size for system cell. Ok, but I wonder if there is more universal approach.

Comment: i guess u r using storyboard!! Why do you want to hardcode ? You can apply constraints directly on storyboard!!!

Comment: No storyboard. What constraints should I apply?

Comment: use masonry for applying constraints!!!! Just apply width and leading/trailing and top/bottom constraint